# Bootstrap 5 Cards Displayed Vertically

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-cards

I have some cards on my webpage currently displayed horizontally in a row. I am wanting to make these move to display vertically on a smaller screen. At the moment, they just go off the page when the screen is shrunk. I still want the cards to be equally spread apart (currently using `.justify-content-between`). The code for the cards are

```
    <!-- Cards -->  
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around mb-3">
    <div class="p-2">
        <div class="card" style="width:400px">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/i3-10105F.jpg" alt="Card image">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Intel i3-10105F <span class="badge bg-success">New</span></h4>
                    <h5 class="card-title">$130</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        4 Cores 8 Threads <br>
                        Core Clock: 3.70 GHz <br>
                        Boost Clock: 4.40 GHz <br>
                        LGA1200 Socket
                    </p>
                    <a href="https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/products/sku/203474/intel-core-i310105f-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz/specifications.html?wapkw=i3-10105F" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">More Information</a>
                    <a href="https://www.computeralliance.com.au/intel-s1200-core-i3-10105f-3.7ghz-quad-core-cpu-bx8070110105f" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2">
        <div class="card" style="width:400px">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/i5-11600KF.jpg" alt="Card image">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Intel i5-11600KF <span class="badge bg-success">New</span></h4>
                    <h5 class="card-title">$389</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        6 Cores 12 Threads <br>
                        Core Clock: 3.90 GHz <br>
                        Boost Clock: 4.90 GHz <br>
                        LGA1200 Socket
                    </p>
                    <a href="https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/products/sku/212276/intel-core-i511600kf-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz/specifications.html" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">More Information</a>
                    <a href="https://www.computeralliance.com.au/intel-s1200-core-i5-11600kf-3.9ghz-six-core-cpu-(no-cooler)-bx8070811600kf" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2">
        <div class="card" style="width:400px">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/i9-11900K.jpg" alt="Card image">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Intel i9-11600K <span class="badge bg-secondary">Recommended</span></h4>
                    <h5 class="card-title">$749</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        8 Cores 16 Threads <br>
                        Core Clock: 3.50 GHz <br>
                        Boost Clock: 5.30 GHz <br>
                        LGA1200 Socket
                    </p>
                    <a href="https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/products/sku/212325/intel-core-i911900k-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-30-ghz/specifications.html?wapkw=i9-11900k" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">More Information</a>
                    <a href="https://www.computeralliance.com.au/intel-s1200-core-i9-11900k-3.50ghz-8-core-cpu-(no-cooler)-bx8070811900k" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are hard setting widths on your cards. You could use the column classes instead. Look up how to use the Bootstrap Grid System or the Bootstrap Column system. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the grid classes (`row > col`) for responsive behavior. For example...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-around mb-3">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card" style="width:400px">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/i3-10105F.jpg" alt="Card image">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Intel i3-10105F <span class="badge bg-success">New</span></h4>
                    <h5 class="card-title">$130</h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> 4 Cores 8 Threads <br> Core Clock: 3.70 GHz <br> Boost Clock: 4.40 GHz <br> LGA1200 Socket </p>
                    <a href="https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/products/sku/203474/intel-core-i310105f-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz/specifications.html?wapkw=i3-10105F" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">More Information</a>
                    <a href="https://www.computeralliance.com.au/intel-s1200-core-i3-10105f-3.7ghz-quad-core-cpu-bx8070110105f" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card" style="width:400px">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/i5-11600KF.jpg" alt="Card image">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Intel i5-11600KF <span class="badge bg-success">New</span></h4>
                    <h5 class="card-title">$389</h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> 6 Cores 12 Threads <br> Core Clock: 3.90 GHz <br> Boost Clock: 4.90 GHz <br> LGA1200 Socket </p>
                    <a href="https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/products/sku/212276/intel-core-i511600kf-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz/specifications.html" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">More Information</a>
                    <a href="https://www.computeralliance.com.au/intel-s1200-core-i5-11600kf-3.9ghz-six-core-cpu-(no-cooler)-bx8070811600kf" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card" style="width:400px">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/i9-11900K.jpg" alt="Card image">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Intel i9-11600K <span class="badge bg-secondary">Recommended</span></h4>
                    <h5 class="card-title">$749</h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> 8 Cores 16 Threads <br> Core Clock: 3.50 GHz <br> Boost Clock: 5.30 GHz <br> LGA1200 Socket </p>
                    <a href="https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/products/sku/212325/intel-core-i911900k-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-30-ghz/specifications.html?wapkw=i9-11900k" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">More Information</a>
                    <a href="https://www.computeralliance.com.au/intel-s1200-core-i9-11900k-3.50ghz-8-core-cpu-(no-cooler)-bx8070811900k" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/RX3tviIzOB

Note: Fixed width cards don't work well for responsiveness.

Comment: Alright. Thanks I will try that out